# I want to make a voip Call using my program

Tags: android, sip, voip

I'm currently developing an application for making VoIP/SIP calls, but I don't know why I cannot make a call to a number using my program. I have a valid SIP server_id, password and domain. Using that domain call can be made. Programming code is given below. Can anyone help me out?

```
public class CallActivity extends Activity {
    public String sipAddress = "nizamcs@sip2sip.info";
    public SipManager manager = null;
    public SipProfile me = null;
    public SipAudioCall call = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calling);
    initializeManager();
}
public void initializeManager() {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}
public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }
    String username = "my_username";
    String domain = "my_domain";
    String password = "my_password";
    if (username.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0 || password.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);




        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                      Log.d("onRegistering", "Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Log.d("onRegistrationDone", "RegistrationDone..Ready");

                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                        String errorMessage) {
                    Log.d("onRegistrationFailed", "RegistrationFailed");

                }
            });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
    } catch (SipException se) {
    }

    initiateCall();
}
  public void closeLocalProfile() {
        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (me != null) {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy",
                    "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
        }
    }
  public void initiateCall() {


        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    call.startAudio();
                    call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                    call.toggleMute();
                   // updateStatus(call);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                }
            };

            call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 300);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
            if (me != null) {
                try {
                    manager.close(me.getUriString());
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                            "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (call != null) {
                call.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So in what way you cannot make a call?

Comment: There is no errors .Inactive input connection

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions in your manifest? `android.permission.USE_SIP` and `android.permission.INTERNET` ?

Comment: yes.cannot make a call means I cant connect to another sip account.

Comment: And I suppose you are using a real device, not an emulator. I am all out of ideas. This code looks fine to me. Sorry

Comment: @foibs Do you have any working code for voip call..can you mail me to noufalm786@gmail.com

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't have.

Comment: You could try tweaking the SIP address to see if that's the issue. Suggestions "nizamcs@sip2sip.info:5060", "sip:nizamcs@sip2sip.info" and "nizmacs@81.23.228.140".

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your request is being send by using wireshark and see the response you get from the sip server. By doing it you can make sure if the request is actually being send or not.